# How to view/access digital pin status and analog pin values of XBee

Tags: xbee

XBee has digital and analog pins.

Before hooking two XBees on API mode on radio, we want to first confirm the analog values from the sensor in order to range for scaling it to engineering value of the sensor. (E.g. scaling 0-65535 to say -20 - +40 deg C).

Is there a way we could check the pin status/values? We couldn't find this capability in XCTU software (or may be we don't know where it is).

Is it possible to see these values on serial port of XBee in computer (e.g. Raspberry pi)?

Comment: Have you looked at the `ATIS` command?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read serial data from remote xbee by connecting coordinator xbee(at PC) to its TX to DIN and RX to DOUT. That is for arduino uno. Then on serial, it will print 24 packets of data and digital data will be on 20 and 21 and analog data will be on 22 and 23.